# Directory sync across SSHFS involving symlinks

Tags: ssh, symlink, sshfs

I have 2 Ubuntu Linux boxes with similar directory structures, LX02 and LX04. When I ssh from a terminal on LX02 to LX04 and go to my main scripting directory, /root/sbin, I see a different set of subdirectories than when I go the same directory from a terminal session on LX04. Why?

**DETAILS**
Both machines have a /0 directory that contains mountpoint directories for each remote host as in...

```
/0/LX02
/0/LX04
```

/etc/fstab contains entries to mount the remote host's root (/) directory to these. There is a 'mount bind' entry to mount the local (/) directory which avoids special coding for the local host in scripts.

/root/sbin is a symlink to /usr/local/sbin on each machine.

*The local /root/sbin directory on LX02 looks like...*

```
 root@LX02:/  cd /root/sbin

 root@LX02:~/sbin  ls -l | grep '^d'

drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2011-07-16 00:49 Archives-sbin-20110825
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2010-07-28 08:13 lst
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Misc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Slates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Tomboy
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Ubuntu_8.04
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2010-07-28 08:13 www
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-09-27 12:48 zim
```

*Going to /0/LX04/root/sbin from an LX02 terminal session results in...*

```
 root@LX02:/0/LX04/root/sbin  cd /0/LX04/root/sbin

 root@LX02:/0/LX04/root/sbin  ls -l | grep '^d'

drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2011-07-16 00:49 Archives-sbin-20110825
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2010-07-28 08:13 lst
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Misc
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Slates
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Tomboy
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-04-11 09:28 Ubuntu_8.04
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2010-07-28 08:13 www
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 2012-09-27 12:48 zim
```

*However, the /root/sbin directory on LX04 actually looks like...*

```
 root@LX04:/  cd /root/sbin

 root@LX04:~/sbin  ls -l | grep '^d'

drwx------ 4 root root 12288 2011-12-23 03:23 Archives
drwx------ 2 root root  4096 2011-07-16 00:49 Archives-sbin-20110825
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 2012-11-14 00:22 Examples
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2011-04-29 13:50 fnc
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2011-05-19 15:00 lst
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 2012-10-28 10:01 Synergy
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2011-03-10 20:54 tmp
drwxr-x--- 2 root root  4096 2011-03-10 20:54 www
```

#### What's happening here?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you need root privileges to log on at the machines? Can you reproduce this issue with an unprivileged user? What does `grep root /etc/passwd` return on both machines?

Comment: No, I'm not... but thanks for asking as it could be a factor for most people.

I leave to those who still have to work in multiuser environments to address those kinds of questions.

I have a "salvage yard" of several Linux computers (I like to think of it as a "lab") and 99% of what I do on them requires root privileges so logging in as an unprivileged user would be very unproductive.

So far as I can tell, no bots have slaved my machines yet. I predominantly rely on monitoring the history of what normally runs, and the resource usage, and watch for anomalies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your setup correctly, `/root/sbin` on LX04 is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/sbin`. Therefore `/0/LX04/root/sbin` on LX02, which is part of an SSHFS filesystem, is a symbolic link to `/usr/local/sbin`. When you're on LX02, the directory `/0/LX04/root/sbin` is located at `/usr/local/sbin`, and that's the contents you're seeing. Since you're on LX02, you are of course seeing LX02's `/usr/local/sbin` (which is also accessible via `/root/sbin`).

Symbolic links are purely textual, they don't carry any information about the filesystem that you think they should be targetting.

If you want `/0/LX04/root/sbin` to point to the `/usr/local/sbin` from LX04, make it a symbolic to `/0/LX04/usr/local/sbin`. If you want `/0/LX04/root/sbin` to show `/usr/local/sbin` from the same machine that it's on (which here is the same thing), make it a relative link: `/root/sbin ->../usr/local/sbin` (run `ln -snf ../usr/local/sbin /0/LX04/root/sbin`. It's usually a good idea to make symbolic links relative, that more often than not gives the desired result when doing complex mounting.

Comment: I'd vote this up but I haven't got enough rep yet!

Yes, I finally figured that out but left the question up so I can find the answer next time I need it (I forget a lot).

Comment: Now that I have enough rep, I've +1'd. Thanks!